# Spark Drop Duplicates Removes All Rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
val df = spark.read
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")
        .option("url", url) 
        .option("dbtable", table)
        .option("user", username)
        .option("password", password).load()

df.where(col("code") === "XFH").show()
df.dropDuplicates("code").where(col("code") === "XFH").show()
```

My data has two entries for `code == XFH`, so I would expect two rows to be returned for the first show, and one to be returned for the second. However, I'm getting two for the first and then zero for the second (i.e. it is removing both duplicates).

If I try the following, it works as expected so I believe it's to do with having multiple columns (although I've been unable to reproduce the issue with a dummy data set):

```
df.select("code").dropDuplicates("code").where(col("acf_code") === "code").show()
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it so that my data frame only contains a single instance of XFH?

**Update:** I've also tried splitting into separate stages, as suggested by @GamingFelix.

```
val dedupDf = df.dropDuplicates("code")

println(df.count())
// Prints 694
println(dedupDf.count())
// Prints 692
```

There's only the one row that is duplicated, so it appears it's still dropping both rows.

**Update 2:**

So it appears that it's not `dropDuplicates` that is the issue, but something else odd is going on.

```
df.where(col("code") === "XFH").show()
// Returns 2 results

df.dropDuplicates("code").where(col("code") === "XFH").show()
// Returns 0 results

df.dropDuplicates("code").where(trim(col("code")) === "XFH").show()
// Returns 1 result, as desired
```

I don't really understand why I need to wrap the column in a trim, even though the equality test of the first statement works fine without it (i.e. there are no spaces to trim).

Comment: can you add a code to create a sample data?

Comment: @Raghu - as I said above, I've not been able to reproduce the issue on dummy data (and I can't share the real data)

Comment: If you to removed duplicates,you can use dropDuplicates() function which return a new DataFrame with duplicate rows removed. https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-remove-duplicate-rows/

Comment: @tarun - I'm aware of that, did you actually read the question?

Comment: Hi James! I think one the second one, you actually do dropDuplicates on two columns. What happens if you do val dropped = df.dropDuplicates("code") and then do dropped.filter(col("code") === "XFH").show()

Comment: @GamingFelix - Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried separating them, and added an update above. Unfortunately, it didn't seem to help :-(

Comment: The only logical conclusion is that you actually have 3 entries of that and when you drop duplicates you're removing 2 of them. I'd recommend you look at the specific column only. Then do a filter on that specific entry.  I also think it could be worthwhile for you to check the distinct function with the counts.

Comment: Also, I want to add. I've been assuming that you don't have other duplicates. But in fact, when you do this -> val dedupDf = df.dropDuplicates("code")  you are actually dropping duplicates for all entries inside code. That means if there's another duplicate of another entry, you're also dropping that at the same time. That is the only other option to you having 3 entries.

Comment: And, it would make sense with your other code too, that it is actually not ONLY dropping the entry you are looking at, but another one too.

Comment: I can confirm there are definitely only two duplicate entries (as after this I insert into a database with a primary key defined, and it complains only about XFH); and if I look at the results there are no XFH results at all afterwards so there are not 3 entries.

Comment: Could you actually display / print the result you are getting? When you filter for that ("XFH"). For distincts..etc? Seems way morel likely to me that you are missing something, rather then that dropDuplicates is broken

Comment: Like, does println(df.distinct.count()) give you 692?

Comment: Thanks @GamingFelix, I've added another update above. Wrapping the column with a `trim()` seems to work, even though there should be nothing to trim. I've no idea why that works, some subtly of Spark I'm missing perhaps! Cheers for your help.

Comment: trim removes whitespace. It could be that you had a second or third element that was "XFH " or " XFH". No problems!